# Unauthorized error when connecting to TFS 2015 portal from TFS App Tier server

Tags: azure, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm attempting to get my TFS 2015 up and running in Azure and i'm running into an odd authorization issue. If I remote into the Azure VM and try to go to the TFS Portal (https://tfs.XXXX.net/tfs) I get prompted for credentials and get the unauthorized error after 3 attempts. However, if i try to get to that URL from my own Laptop, the URL comes up with no issues. I'm not even asked to log in since its usign integrated authentication. (same could be said of the VM since I'm logging in as the Service account) I have some final configurations around the SharePoint foundations install/setup that I need to finish that requires the URL be tested and authorized in order for the settings to work and i'm not able to get past it.

A few other details:
1. This is an Azure VM
2. the VM is attached to my companies domain
3. the VM is connected to a VPN connection between azure and my company
4. TFS is set up to use AD and authenticate back to the OnPrem AD

Comment: On the VM, which credentials do you use to authenticate with TFS? Yours or the Service Account credentials? Have you tried entering domain\username for the credentials?

Comment: I used both my creds and the service account. Both work outside of the VM, but neither work from the VM itself

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I do add the domain as well. no difference.

Comment: How about access the portal from https://localhost/tfs?